# How are figures drawn in academic articles?

Tags: technical-drawing, draw

I wonder in general how professional looking, quality figures are drawn in academic papers, especially 3D cross-sections, isometric views and such. Is it usually `Tikz`/`Asymptote` or are there other softwares used for this purpose? For example I have the following figures, which program are they drawn with in your opinion?

[image]

[image]

**1**  Minovich, A.; Klein, A. E.; Janunts, N.; Pertsch, T.; Neshev, D. N. & Kivshar, Y. S. Generation and Near-Field Imaging of Airy Surface Plasmons Phys. Rev. Lett., American Physical Society, 2011, 107, 116802

**2** Oubo You ; Benfeng Bai ; Xiaoyu Wu ; Zhendong Zhu ; Qixia Wang; 
Effective generation of unidirectional SPP beam with arbitrary profile
. Proc. SPIE 9890, Optical Micro- and Nanometrology VI, 98900W (April 26, 2016); doi:10.1117/12.2227668.

Comment: Unlikely that TikZ is involved for those I'd say, but of course there are other software available for drawing stuff. However, asking which one is, I fear, a) probably off-topic here, and b) perhaps impossible to answer conclusively. You could send an email to the first author and ask (the address is easy to find).

Comment: See also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/software-to-draw-illustrative-figures-in-papers and https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/76874/which-tools-should-be-used-to-produce-charts-in-computer-science-research-papers?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://www.quora.com/What-software-do-physicists-use-to-draw-the-diagrams-in-the-papers-they-published

Comment: More probably some 3D modeller/raytracing program (povray, blender, etc.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I thought it was Tikz maybe that is why I asked it here, probably academia.stackexchange.com would have been better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That I know of (in physics):

- Inkscape *
- Paint
- Photoshop * / GIMP *
- PowerPoint / OpenOffice *
- TikZ *
- Adobe Illustrator
- any number of CAD and solid modelling packages (though their output conversion can be disappointing)
- Python (for graph-like figures e.g. sketch graphs of idealised systems) *
- Blender

* indicates ones I've used personally (including in my thesis)

This excludes pure graphs (results) as the list would be too long.

I've seen illustrator used for some pretty impressive figures including in 3d, but if I had to reproduce that top figure I'd start with a 3d modelling package and finish in Inkscape. If I had plenty of time I'd use it as an excuse to learn blender or go retro and play with POVray.

For the second figure I'd plot the graphs in Origin or Python (plenty of other options but PDF output is good from both of those) and finish the job in Inkscape.

Comment: If people want to add to this (assuming the question doesn't get closed, which having read the comments I think it might) please do so. It could be a community wiki answer.

Comment: By the way, I don't rule out quality figures in paint. It's not impossible, just difficult and unlikely. And a bad idea given the quality of open source tools.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer I am thinking of asking the question to first authors too as stated above.